# Copy part of the file in the buffer

Tags: buffers, files, copy-paste

I need to copy part of the file (with `re-search-forward`) to another file under the marker. I know how to use `re-search-forward`, but I have problems with buffer.

Am i right with my logic?

- 1) open needed file with temp buffer
- 2) create new buffer
- 3) find needed lines with `re-search-forward` and copy them in this new
  buffer
- 4) insert lines into opened file with `insert-buffer-substring`

Right now i have a function like this:

```el
(defun my-insert-file-name (filename)
  (interactive "*fInsert file name: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (when (re-search-forward "#here")
      (forward-line 1)
      (------something should be here-----)))
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert text from this other file in to the current buffer? Or are you trying to insert text from the current buffer in to another file? You might be able to use `append-to-buffer` or `append-to-file` but I'm not entirely clear on your requirements here.

Comment: Yes, i want to insert text from other file to current buffer

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood the question properly, here's a starting point:

```
(defun my-insert-file-name (filename)
  (interactive "*fInsert file name: ")
  (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
    (save-excursion
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert-file-contents filename)
        (goto-char 1)
        (re-search-forward "regexp")
        (append-to-buffer buf (point) (point-max))))))
```

What this is doing:

- Set `buf` to the current buffer.
- Insert the contents of `filename` in to a new temporary buffer.
- Go to the top of the temporary buffer and search forward for "regexp".
- Insert the contents of the temporary buffer from the line after the match to the end of the file back in to `buf`.